# ggplot: Plotting the bins on x-axis and the average on y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, binning

Suppose that I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10,0,1), x = runif(10,0,1))
```

What I would like to do is to cut the x values into bins, such as:

```
data$bins <- cut(data$x,breaks = 4)
```

Then, I would like to plot (using ggplot) the result in a way that the x-axis is the bins, and the y axis is the mean of data$y data points that fall into the corresponding bin.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I see your question asks to cut values and then plot averages. A more statistically sound approach to finding bins using a standard algorithm in the `hist` function like `> tmp <- hist(data.x, breaks="Sturges") ` and then using something like `idxs = findInterval(data.x, tmp$breaks)`. Then use the indices for x coordinates in ggplot: `tmp$mids[idxs]` and the averages on y using the solution suggested by @christoph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `stat_summary()` function.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10,0,1), x = runif(10,0,1))
data$bins <- cut(data$x,breaks = 4)
# Points:
ggplot(data, aes(x = bins, y = y)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point")

# Histogram bars:
ggplot(data, aes(x = bins, y = y)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "histogram")
```

Here is the picture of the points:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This thread is a bit old but here you go, use stat_summary_bin (it might be in the newer versions).

```
ggplot(data, mapping=aes(x, y)) +
stat_summary_bin(fun.y = "mean", geom="bar", bins=4 - 1) +
ylab("mean")
```

[image: Here is a picture]

Answer (score 1):

Since the mean of your y values can be smaller than 0, I recommend a dot plot instead of a bar chart. The dots represent the means. You can use either qplot or the regular ggplot function. The latter is more customizable. In this example, both produce the same output.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(7)
data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10,0,1), x = runif(10,0,1))
data$bins <- cut(data$x,breaks = 4, dig.lab = 2)

qplot(bins, y, data = data, stat="summary", fun.y = "mean")

ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(bins), y = y)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point")
```

You can also add error bars. In this case, they show the mean +/- 1.96 times the group standard deviation. The group mean and SD can be obtained using tapply.

```
m <- tapply(data$y, data$bins, mean)
sd <- tapply(data$y, data$bins, sd)
df <- data.frame(mean.y = m, sd = sd, bin = names(m))

ggplot(df, aes(x = bin, y = mean.y, 
               ymin = mean.y - 1.96*sd, 
               ymax = mean.y + 1.96*sd)) + 
  geom_errorbar() + geom_point(size = 3)
```

[image]